# Sections in the answer box header aren't sectioned properly when logged out on mobile

Tags: bug, editor, responsive-design

On mobile, this is the layout that you would normally see when logged in to the site:

> [image: Image of answer box with properly sectioned header]

However, on sites where you can post as a guest, logging out results in this layout *when the answer box is **inactive***:

> [image: Image of answer box with irregularly sectioned header]

Note how the sections in the answer box header aren't sectioned properly as compared to the first screenshot.

Comment: This is also how it appears on iOS. The lines go to the correct places when you start writing an answer though.